# Uploading sketch with teensyduino

Tags: teensy

In case I upload a sketch to a teensy board via the Arduino IDE (teensyduino), should any of the TX/RX pins of the teensy be unoccupied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the Teensy boards have a dedicated micro USB connector for programming via the Arduino IDE. The USB1_DP and USB1_DN (for the USB port) are the only pins that are reserved, so you can freely use all of the TX/RX pins that are available.